# equals() doesn't work as expected with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to compare current URL with a string URL, but the following code returns `false`.

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");       
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("https://www.facebook.com"));
```

Comment: Welcome to stack! Put `driver.getCurrentUrl()`into a variable, and let us know what that is when you step through the code.

Comment: printing the variable give me https://www.facebook.com/ but It stills returns false .

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, when you step through the code, let us know what `driver.getCurrentUrl()` returns, it should be a string, not a boolean

Comment: driver.getCurrentUrl() return  a java.lang.String

Comment: Yes, but what is the string? Is it `"http://someotherurlthanyouwereexpecting?"`

Comment: no the string returned by driver.getCurrentUrl() is https://www.facebook.com/ as expected but for some reason the .equals() operation is returning false.

Comment: you can do `"https://www.facebook.com".contains(driver.getCurrentUrl()`

Comment: sorry just saw your edited comments. it looks like you're comparing `https://www.facebook.com` with `https://www.facebook.com/` which are not equal (notice the slash at the end). But it's hard to say for sure with the unformatted link.

Comment: @AbbasGoherKhan is your question solved? if yes, please accept the best answer. Also, don't forget to upvote other good answers.

Answer (score 4):

I tried your code, and the URL that is being returned by `driver.getCurrentUrl()` was `"https://www.facebook.com/"`

Since you are doing an `equals` check with `"https://www.facebook.com"`, it will return false because of the missing `'/'` at the end of returned URL. Either compare it with this URL being returned, or use `contains()` to check if url returned is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `equals()` try to use `startsWith()`:

> driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("https://www.facebook.com")

or `contains()`:

> driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("https://www.facebook.com")

This approach will be much better.
For using `equals()` you need to have ***exactly the same*** path which you expect.

However with `contains()` or `startsWith()` you can check expected behaviour and make an assertion.

I created some demo code:

```
public class FacebookDemoTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        driver = DriverManager.getInstance();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testContainsAndStartsWith() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("CURRENT URL:" + driver.getCurrentUrl());

        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("https://www.facebook.com"));
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("https://www.facebook.com"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("CURRENT URL:" + driver.getCurrentUrl());

        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("https://www.facebook.com"));
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().contentEquals("https://www.facebook.com"));
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        DriverManager.closeQuietly();
    }
}
```

Here is results:

[image]

and current URL from console log:

> CURRENT URL:https://www.facebook.com/

Comment: What if the URL returned starts with facebook.com but ends with something completely different than the home page, like some users page, etc. Then your `.contains()` test will pass when it really shouldn't. The best answer is to compare it to "https://www.facebook.com/" with `.equals()` and you will know for sure whether it's correct or not.

Comment: @JeffC if you know exactly which path you have to get - you have to use `equals()`

Answer (score 0):

OR, you can go with:

```
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("https://www.facebook.com"));
```

Because sometimes sites add diff parameters to their URLs to control statistics (e.g. some geo stuff).
:)